# Trying to be good

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy

When browsing on my computer, I have had about three times that i wandered to the inappropriate videos from youtube. B"H I have never gone to an inappropriate site and don't plan on. After each time I felt horrible  about myself and feel like a traitor to all those around me who would never suspect this of me. I am a role model for teens, and feel like if they would only know.... I want to block youtube, but know that I need it for work. Am I a bad person? Is this normal? Please answer me, because I trly want to be a good eved Hashem and do whats right and be Echad B'peh and lev, and mind as well.
Thank You!

Comment: Just keep trying your best. Hatzlacha in all that you do!

Comment: Use http://www.frumtube.com/